# SQL Selecting only records matching year and month between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I am making a SQL procedure to get me a selection of workers from the table,
where each worker has `startJob` and `endJob` date.

What I need is to make selection of all the workers who were on the job
during specified `@year` and `@month`. (@year & @month are input params)
I would really appreciate an advice how to solve this the easiest way.

Thx for any help.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a date from the year and month parameters and compare to the start and end job fields.
This will return the first day of the month/year entered, and return results where this date is between the StartJob and EndJob

```
select *
from worker

where
 CAST(
      CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(01 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS DATETIME)

between 
StartJob and EndJob
```

Comment: Is your @month a numeric value, or the month name?

Comment: Apologies, I've taken another look and edited my original answer. This assumes your month is a numeric value.

Comment: yes, i was looking for this solution, works great, thank you OWSam

Answer (score 1):

If i proper understood you then try something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_Procedure]
  @Year  int
, @Month int
AS
BEGIN
  select * from workers
  where @Year between YEAR(startJob) and YEAR(endJob)
    and @Month between MONTH(startJob) and MONTH(endJob)
END
```

Comment: Really? Think for example about case, when worker started job in December and ended in January [after some years]...

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DATE` based on the start of the month for the given year

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 1999
DECLARE @Month INT = 1
DECLARE @Date DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR, @Month) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR, @Month) + '-01')

-- SQL Server should now correctly handle the logic to filter out the relevant rows
SELECT * 
FROM worker w
WHERE @Date BETWEEN w.startJob AND w.endJob
```

If you'd rather use the last day of the month, then you could use `EOMONTH(@Month)` for your `DAY`.

Comment: In second case you mean YEAR(w.startJob) <= @year and not between, right?

Comment: I am sorry, but that example is the first thing I tried. unfortunatelly it  doesn't work as planned.

Comment: also works, with a little mistake, it should've been @Year converting first, but i've seen it. thx for help Alex

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL SOLVED SELECT ROWS BETWEEN TWO DATE USING ONLY MONTH AND YEAR**

```
begin
declare @trvl_start_date as date
declare @trvl_stop_date as date

declare @trim_start as varchar(20)
declare @trim_end as varchar(20)

declare  @trvl_start_date_new as date
declare  @trvl_stop_date_new as date

set @trvl_start_date ='2015-10-12'
set @trvl_stop_date='2016-01-01'
set @trim_start = LEFT(@trvl_start_date, CHARINDEX('-', @trvl_start_date) + 2) + '-01'
set @trim_end = LEFT(@trvl_stop_date, CHARINDEX('-', @trvl_stop_date) + 2) + '-01'

print @trim_start
print @trim_end

set @trvl_start_date_new = @trim_start
set @trvl_stop_date_new =dateadd(month,-1,@trim_end)

print @trvl_start_date_new
print @trvl_stop_date_new

SELECT   fee_catg_srno      FROM   dbo.fee_catg_tbl
                                        WHERE   (acd_yr = 1) AND (recycle = 1) AND (acc_head_srno = 3) AND pay_date between @trvl_start_date_new and    @trvl_stop_date_new 


end
```